# create dynamic html table with dynamic tr ,td using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

how can I create an html table from a json file, which I do not know the number of columns or the number of rows (the number of row ng-repeat enough),
this json file is editable and the number of column and row change

Comment: you should ask something more specific, show some code and explain what is the exact problem you are facing. Always refer to this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You would need to load your JSON file into your app with either the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) or [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) service. This is best done in a service, which you would inject whereever you need your data.

```
this.getJson = function() {  // real json get
   $http.get('/api/GetJson').then(function(data) {
      return data;
});
```

};

I created a [small plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8axGmc0amvnXQyLeYWT9?p=preview) with a service that holds my fake getJson function which returns the json data with the rows. Then I injected the service into my HomeController and put the rows on the $scope.

```
 $scope.rows = loadJsonService.getFakeJson().rows;
```

When the rows are on the $scope, you only have to use the ngRepeat directive to create your table structure.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr class="row" ng-repeat="row in rows">
      <th>row {{$index + 1}}</th>
      <td class="column" ng-repeat="column in row.column">{{column}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```